# Spawning Multiple rdesktop sessions with Python

Tags: python

I am writing a script to launch remote desktop sessions using rdesktop. The relevant portion of the code looks like this:

```
subprocess.call(["rdesktop", "-a 16", "-u user", "-g 1280x1024",, server])
```

When this happens, the terminal is locked up until I exit the rdesktop session. Would it be possible to launch multiple desktop sessions with this script?

Comment: Use `subprocess.Popen` instead of `subprocess.call`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`subprocess.Popen` ([py2 docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen), [py3 docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen)) is the correct answer here. 
`subprocess.call` waits for the command to complete, while `subprocess.Popen` calls it in the background, and immediately executes the next line.

Answer (score 0):

You can fork the python process or use threads, or run the process in the background.